# Why the blackslash dot (\.) in the prefix of the path?

Tags: find, path

I was running the find command looking for some config files and this is exactly what it outputted:

```
 ./log4j.xml
 ./log4j2-test.xml
 ./proxyserver/src/main/resources/log4j.xml
 ./proxyserver/target/classes/log4j.xml
 ./proxyui/src/main/resources/log4j.xml
 \./proxyui/src/test/resources/log4j.xml
 ./proxyui/target/classes/log4j.xml
 ./proxyui/target/odo/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml
 ./proxyui/target/test-classes/log4j.xml
```

Why does the sixth one down the way that it is? I tried opening the file

```
\./proxyui/src/test/resources/log4j.xml
```

and I believe it is the same file as the one that is at

```
./proxyui/src/test/resources/log4j.xml
```

So why is that backslash there at the front?

Comment: I think it´s because the log4j.xml is found as main and test. The test is escaped (disabled), because your main is activated. [But only guessing ;)]

Comment: Peculiar. Try piping the output to `od -t x1z -w24` and locate the name and backslash there... _(od will display both a hex and an ascii type listing for what you pipe into it)_

Comment: I'm on Mac OSX and its 'od' command doesn't support the -t x1z option. Anyway, I manually inspected the output of the same find command and the backslash is gone...so maybe it was just a bug in find?

Comment: My guess is that you accidentally bumped the `\ ` key while `find` was running, and your `\ ` echoed on the screen in the middle of `find`'s output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm accepting G-Man's comment as the answer:

"My guess is that you accidentally bumped the \  key while find was running, and your \  echoed on the screen in the middle of find's output."

The other possibility that it's a bug in find or some paths have a \ in front seems much more unlikely

Comment: Either let him rewrite his comment as an answer and then accept it, or accept your own answer. As it is now, the question is left with no accepted answer. :) Cheers!